# AngularJs directive change ngModel with delay & model's value don't match

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change

Ng-change is acting weird in a directive. It seems to have a delay in the digest cycle resulting in the wrong (previous) ngModel value in controller immediately after the change.

```
ngModel : '='
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moEgdG

What's going on and how to fix?

Comment: You can pass correct value to changer() function & equate ngModel to it there. But it doesn't feel to be right.

Comment: Yes, the two-way binding (`=`) creates a watcher that transfers the data from the parent scope to the isolate scope of the directive. That transfer requires a digest cycle. That's the way the AngularJS framework works.

Comment: yes, but why it seems it has a delay?

Answer (score 1):

With the `ng-model` directive on a component, I recommend using one-way (`<`) for the input and [$setViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue) on the output:

```
app.directive('newTag', function(){
  return {
    template: `
       <input ng-model="test" ng-change="change(test)"> <br/>
       {{test}}
    `,
    restrict: 'E',
    require: "ngModel",  
    scope: {
        ngModel : '<',
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.change = function(val) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(val);
      };
    },
  };
})
```

Usage:

```
<new-tag ng-model="tagValue" ng-change("newTagUpdate(tagValue)")>
</new-tag>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#overview)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)

Comment: probably will work in angularjs 1.5+ and good for transition to angular2
but what to do in older versions?

Comment: `ng-change("newTagUpdate(tagValue)")` 
As I've sad already I can do that in two way binding either, but what the point of two way binding then?!

Comment: To make migration to Angular +2 easier, components should avoid two-way binding. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Reference - Component-base application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)